# can we use www for both the internet and intranet URLs

Tags: url, web, dns, intranet

I have a server which can be accessed with internal IP(intranet) and external (Internet).

Can i use the same URL(www.example.com) to access web content from  for both intranet and internet ? .

Mainly can i use www in the intranet DNS also ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as DNS is concerned, www has no special significance, it is just a hostname.

Presuming your internal nameserver and your external one are not the same! this is perfectly possible. If you're external webserver is at 12.34.56.78 and your internal one is at 192.168.0.1 then you can use

On your internal network

www IN A 192.168.0.1

and on your external network

www.IN A 12.34.56.78

However you should be aware that if you map www.example.com to the internal website, then you won't be able to access the external site internally.